# Tumblr jQuery Pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, tumblr

I'm trying to paginate Tumblr's API v1 output on my website. I have the jQuery code and it works fine when displaying content, however, I need to allow it to become split and paginated for organizational purposes. The first box of code calls the API when

`<div id="content"><div id=main"><div id ="tumblrFeed"></div><div class="clear"></div></div>`

is called on the html page.

I'm having trouble being able to paginate my content when it's output on the browser. As you can see I have each page display 5 posts, and I've declared the variable tumblrPaginate to start at 0. I need the variable to change each time the user clicks on a "Previous or Next" button.

I've been working on this for quite some time, ballpark range is 2 weeks, without success. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated. Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner with Javascript, jQuery, and the like.

```
    var tumblr_api_read = null; // this is important do not remove
    var tumblrPaginate = 0; // **TODO** make loop to increment each for pagination feature
    var tumblrpostCount = 5; // set the post count number, max is 50 for API v1

    $(document).ready(function() {  
            // setup our namespace
            $.tumblr = {};
            // modify these
            $.tumblr.url = 'http://wisdmlab.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?&num=' + tumblrpostCount +'&start=' + tumblrPaginate +''; // set to display 7 posts. off set syntax is start=[postnumtobeginat]
            $.tumblr.numPostsToDisplay = 50;
            $.tumblr.postMaxDescriptionLength = 500; // set to -1 to turn off jquery.expander
            $.tumblr.videoWidth='200'; // youtube default 400
            $.tumblr.videoHeight='163'; // youtube default 325
            // do not modify these unless you are hardcore
            $.tumblr.imagePath = '..//testscripts/tumblr-jquery-master/img/';   
            $.tumblr.postCount = 0;

            reloadTumblr();
  });       

  function reloadTumblr(){      
    $("#tumblrFeed").empty();
    $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='body'>loading Tumblr</div>");

    $.ajax({
          url: $.tumblr.url,
          dataType: 'script',
          timeout: 10000,
      success:function(){ 
        $("#tumblrFeed").empty();
        if ((tumblr_api_read == undefined) || (tumblr_api_read == null)) {
            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='title' href='#'>unable to load Tumblr</div>");
            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='body'><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"javascript:reloadTumblr();\">[retry]</a></div>");                
            } else {
                //$("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='body'><a href=\"#\" style=\"float:center\" onclick=\"javascript:reloadTumblr();\">Refresh News Page</a></div>");
                $.tumblr.postCount = 0;
            $.each(tumblr_api_read.posts.slice(0, 50), function(i,post){
                        if ($.tumblr.postCount >= $.tumblr.numPostsToDisplay) {
                            return;
                        }               
                    parseTumblrJSON(post);
                    $.tumblr.postCount++;
                });

                // Apply Expander
                if ($.tumblr.postMaxDescriptionLength > -1) {
                      $('div.expandable').expander({
                        slicePoint:       $.tumblr.postMaxDescriptionLength,  // default is 100
                        expandText:         'Read more.',
                        userCollapseText: 'Read less.'
                      });                                   
                }
            }
      },
      error:function (xhr, statusTxt, errorTxt){
            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<a class='title' href='#'>Tumblr Parse Error</a>");
            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='body'>" + errorTxt + "<br/>" + xhr.responseText + "</div>");
      }                           
        });     
  }

    function formatDate(d) {
        return d.toString('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy')
    }

    function processResponse() {
    }

    function parseTumblrJSON(post) {
        //alert(post.type);
        var d = Date.parse(post["date-gmt"]);
        var dateFmt = formatDate(d);

    switch(post.type)
    {               
        case "regular":
        {
                $("#tumblrFeed").append(
                    "<table style='width: 100%;'><tr><td width='18px'>" +
                    "</td></table>");                       
            //Place directly before "</td>" <div class='date'>" + dateFmt + "</div>

            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<a class='title' href='" + post.url + "' target='_blank'>" + (post["regular-title"] == null ? 'view tumblr' : post["regular-title"])  + "</a>");
            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='body expandable'>" + post["regular-body"] + "</div>");
            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='date'>Posted on " + dateFmt + "</div>");
            break;
        }
        case "link":
        {
                $("#tumblrFeed").append(
                    "<table style='width: 100%;'><tr><td width='18px'>" +
                    "<a href='" + post.url + "' target='_blank'>" +
                    "<div class='date'>" + dateFmt + "</div></td></table>");                        

            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<a class='title' href='" + post["link-url"] + "' target='_blank'>" + (post["link-text"] == null ? 'view tumblr' : post["link-text"]) + "</a>");
            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='body expandable'>" + post["link-description"] + "</div>");
            break;
        }               
        case "quote":
        {
                $("#tumblrFeed").append(
                    "<table style='width: 100%;'><tr><td width='18px'>" +
                    "<a href='" + post.url + "' target='_blank'>" +
                    "<div class='date'>" + dateFmt + "</div></td></table>");                        

            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='body'>" + 
                "<div class='quote expandable'>" + post["quote-text"] + "</div>" +
                "<div class='quotesrc'>" + post["quote-source"] + "</div>" +
                "</div>");
            break;
        }               
        case "photo":
        {
                $("#tumblrFeed").append(
                    "<table style='width: 100%;'><tr><td width='18px'>" +
                    "<a href='" + post.url + "' target='_blank'>" +
                    "</td></table>");                       
            // valid values are: photo-url-[75, 100, 250, 400, 500, 1280]
            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='body'>" + 
                "<a href='" + post.url + "'>" +
                "<img src='" + post["photo-url-250"] + "'/></a><br/>" + 
                post["photo-caption"] + 
                "</div>", "<div class='date'>Posted on " + dateFmt + "</div>");
            break;
        }
        case "conversation":
        {
                $("#tumblrFeed").append(
                    "<table style='width: 100%;'><tr><td width='18px'>" +
                    "<a href='" + post.url + "' target='_blank'>" +
                    "<div class='date'>" + dateFmt + "</div></td></table>");                        

            var html = '';
            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<a class='title' href='" + post.url + "' target='_blank'>" + (post["conversation-title"] == null ? 'view tumblr' : post["conversation-title"])  + "</a>");

                for(var i = 0; i < post["conversation"].length; i++) {
                    var conv = post["conversation"][i];                     
                    html += "<div class='convlabel'>" + conv.label + "</div>";
                    html += "<div class='convtext expandable'>" + conv.phrase + "</div>";
                }

                /*          
                $(this).find("line").each(function(){
                    html += "<div class='convlabel'>" + $(this).attr("label") + "</div>";
                    html += "<div class='convtext'>" + $(this).text() + "</div>";
                });*/

            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='body'>" + html + "</div>");
            break;
        }
        case "audio":
        {
                $("#tumblrFeed").append(
                    "<table style='width: 100%;'><tr><td width='18px'>" +
                    "<a href='" + post.url + "' target='_blank'>" +
                    "<div class='date'>" + dateFmt + "</div></td></table>");                        

            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<a class='title' href='" + post.url + "' target='_blank'>" + post["audio-caption"] + "</a>");
            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='body'>" + post["audio-player"] + "</div>");
            break;
        }
        case "video":
        {
                $("#tumblrFeed").append(
                    "<table style='width: 100%;'><tr><td width='18px'>" +
                    "<a href='" + post.url + "' target='_blank'>" +
                    "<div class='date'>" + dateFmt + "</div></td></table>");                        

            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<a class='title' href='" + post.url + "' target='_blank'>" + post["video-caption"] + "</a>");
            // resize our video code if possible
            var vdo = post["video-player"];
            var re = new RegExp('width=\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\"', 'g');
            vdo = vdo.replace(re, 'width="' + $.tumblr.videoWidth + '"');
            re = new RegExp('height=\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\"', 'g');
            vdo = vdo.replace(re, 'height="' + $.tumblr.videoHeight + '"');         
            re = new RegExp('400,320', 'g');
            vdo = vdo.replace(re, $.tumblr.videoWidth + ',' + $.tumblr.videoHeight);
            re = new RegExp('400,250', 'g');
            vdo = vdo.replace(re, $.tumblr.videoWidth + ',' + $.tumblr.videoHeight);
            $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='body'>" + vdo + "</div>");
            break;
        }               
        default:
            break;
    }
    $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I added the controls to the html doc

```
  <div id='controls'>
    <a href="#" id='next'>next</a>:<a href="#" id='previous'>previous</a>
  </div>
```

Then preventDefault the links, increment tumblrPaginate, and reload the tumbler stream:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         (...)
         $.tumblr.imagePath = '..//testscripts/tumblr-jquery-master/img/';
         $.tumblr.postCount = 0;

         $('#next').on( "click", function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             tumblrPaginate += 5;
             reloadTumblr();
         });
         $('#previous').on( "click", function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             if(tumblrPaginate>=5){
                  tumblrPaginate -= 5;
                  reloadTumblr();
             }
         });
         reloadTumblr();
    });
```

And finally in reloadTumblr() you will need to update the $.tumblr.url to include the new tumblrPaginate value:

```
  function reloadTumblr(){
     $("#tumblrFeed").empty();
     $("#tumblrFeed").append("<div class='body'>loading Tumblr</div>");
     $.tumblr.url = 'http://wisdmlab.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?&num=' +
                    tumblrpostCount +'&start=' + tumblrPaginate + '';
     (....)
     }
```

I couldnt get jsFiddle to work, so I uploaded it to my site: [working example](http://projects.bygph.com/tumblrPages/),[js only](http://projects.bygph.com/tumblrPages/jsproblem.js).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I see that the example is working as needed on your website. I tried using the modified js only file you provided, but it's not displaying. Do you think it's because I'm loading the files locally (through wamp)?

Comment: Actually, I think it's just a path issue on my part. Also, I notice that the date isn't working as intended. I'll try to figure it out on my own but do you know why it does that? "Posted on dddd, MMMM d, yyyy" is what I'm seeing as opposed to the actual date of the post.

Comment: Sorry about the date issue, just uncomment `return d.toString('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy')` in `formatDate(d){}` and delete my line that simply returns a string, it should work as before. I commented it out as it seemed i was just missing a script you already had, and wasn't related to the question.

Comment: I tried uncommenting `//return d.toString('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy')`


**from**

`function formatDate(d) {
    //return d.toString('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy')
    return 'dddd, MMMM d, yyyy';
}`

**and removing** `return 'dddd, MMMM d, yyyy';`

**so it would read** `function formatDate(d) {
 return ('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy')
}`

But when I do that no news articles are displayed. Sorry I hope I'm not being too demanding on my requests. You've helped me a great deal, but my Javascript / jQuery knowledge is limited.

Comment: No problems: `function formatDate(d){return d.toString('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy');}` is how it should read

Comment: When I change the code to what you suggested, nothing on news displays.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like it works now. I'm not sure what I changed around but it works. The output looks something like **Posted on Tue Jul 02 2013 16:47:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)** ,which is fine. I'll write a function to output the date differently when needed. 

Once again, thanks for your help!